# Azure Form Recognizer - "TrainingContentMissing", Training data is missing: Could not find any training data at the given path

Tags: python, azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am working with Form Recognizer in Python (version 3.2.1). I'm attempting to train a custom model with pdf's in Azure storage container, code and error below:

```
document_model_admin_client = DocumentModelAdministrationClient(endpoint, credential)

poller = await document_model_admin_client.begin_build_document_model(
    ModelBuildMode.TEMPLATE, blob_container_url="[PATH TO AZURE STORAGE CONTAINER]"
)
model = await poller.result()
```

`

Getting this error below begin_build_document_model():

```
HttpResponseError: (InvalidRequest) Invalid request.
Code: InvalidRequest
Message: Invalid request.
Inner error: {
    "code": "TrainingContentMissing",
    "message": "Training data is missing: Could not find any training data at the given path."
}
```

Any insight into what may be causing this? Already gave permissions on the storage accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This came out yesterday and the portal version works. Looks like Form Recognizer in Azure portal has shifted to Document Intelligence. Try this and hope it helps!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/quickstarts/try-document-intelligence-studio?view=doc-intel-3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The training content missing usually indicates that your training dataset path is incorrect. Check to see if you have a folder or subfolder that you need to add/remove.
If you train from the Studio you should not run into this problem, are you trying this via the API/SDK?